# CentOS permissions for FTP user - 550 Create directory operation failed

Tags: permissions, centos, vsftpd

I have created an ftp user on my CentOS server.

Now I can log in remotely via ftp using my username and password, see all the directory listings (not limited/jailed) to any directory, but I cannot create a new folder.

When I want to create a new directory, it fails:

```
550 Create directory operation failed
```

Note, that I have done the following (when logged in as root):

```
chmod 775 as well as chmod 777
```

as the root user on the server itself(using putty).

NOTE: The folder I want to write to is: /var/www/html

How do I get write access to a specific folder for an FTP user?

I see that I currently have the following permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 6 dextrousdave root 4096 Jul  7 22:30 html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see from `ls` you are missing `w` mark on `group` permissions. It's like `755` on `html` folder

try as root with:

```
chmod 766 -R /var/www/html
```

it should be `drwxrw-rw- dextrousdave root 4096 Jul  7 22:30 html` 
and if you need execute too than do:

```
chmod +x /var/www/html
```

or

```
chmod 777 -R /var/www/html
```

Comment: Cool thank you. But when the user now has access to the /var/www/html folder, will that pose a security threat - Like will he be able to have access up the directory tree (var folder for example)?

Comment: you can check permissions for `ls -lh /var/www`, so if it's `-rw-r--r--` you are safe :) But will have permissions to delete everything in `html/` dir :|

Comment: one more thing, how do i remove the permisisons for a user?

Comment: remove him from all groups that can read/write to html folder with `usermod -G groups,comma,delimited username` read [HERE](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-remove-user-from-group/)